# Motivating the Implication Operator

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I am self-studying from Number Systems and the Foundations of Analysis By Eliott Mendelson.

The book has just defined the truth table for the implication operator and in the following problems seeks to motivate why everything other than T$\Rightarrow$F is evaluated as T. The question begins as follows:

"Verify the following justification for our truth table for A$\Rightarrow$B. It is obvious that $(C\land D)\Rightarrow C$ must always be true. Hence: (i) When $C$ and $D$ are both true, we have $(T\Rightarrow T)=T$. This gives the first row of the table for $\Rightarrow$. (ii) When $C$ is false and $D$ is true, we have $(F\Rightarrow T)=T$, which is the second line of the table. (iii) When $D$ is false, we have $(F\Rightarrow F)=T$, which is the fourth line of the table."

$$\begin{array}{ccc} 
A & B & A\Rightarrow B \\ \hline
T & T &  T\\
F & T & T\\
T & F & F\\
F & F & T
\end{array}$$

My question is what about the assertion $(C\land D)\Rightarrow C$ is obvious? You can of course use the truth table to see that this is true. But if the question is trying to motivate the truth table, I'm left to assume that I can't use the truth table. So it must be true on the basis of an intuitive understanding of implication, or something else.

Can anyone shed light on why this would be an "obvious" assertion?

Comment: As a side note, It seems (ii) is wrong because when C is false and D is true, you should have $F\Rightarrow F$, not  $F\Rightarrow T$. But that isn't central to my question, I don't think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this statement:

"If I have a car and a donkey, then I have a car"

I assume you would consider that true (and all very logical), right?

Well, consider symbolizing as follows:

$C$: I have a car

$D$: I have a donkey

Then the above sentence symbolizes as: $(C \land D) \to C$

I hope you can see that this always works, no matter what $C$ and $D$ are: *if* $C$ and $D$ are both true, then $C$ should be true.

Of course, I am *not* saying that $C \land D$ is true. I am also not sdaying that $C$ is true. But I am saying that $C \land D$ logically implies $C$.  That is: in any situation where $C \land D$ is true, we find that $C$ is true. Or: there is not situation where we finds that $C \land D$ is true, but $C$ is false:  Can you imagine a world where I have both a car and a donkey, but I don't have a car?

So: $C \land D$ *logically* implies $C$.  But if that is the case, then $C \land D$ should always *materially* imply $C$ as well. Hence, $(C \land D) \to C$ should always be true.

Remember that the logical connectives that we mathematically define are meant to capture certain truth-functional relationships. The $\land$, for example, is mean to try and capture what we mean by the English 'and'. When we say 'C and D', we are claiming that both C and D are true. You see this reflected in the truth-table. So it is not that we say that "C and D" is true whenever $C$ and $D$ are true because the truth-table says so, but rather it is just thew other way around: we define the truth-table in a way so as to reflect what we mean by 'and'.

Likewise, we try to capture the truth-functional relationship expressed by any English 'if ... then ...' statement by mathematically defining a $\to$ truth-functional operator. Now, our conception of the 'if ... then ...' is such that when we say 'If both $C$ and $D$ are true, then in particular $C$ is true by itself', we expect to have just stated a true 'if ... then ...' claim.  And, we feel that this should be true no matter the truths of $C$ and $D$. If I say 'If I have a car and a donkey, then I have a car', then any 'normal' speaker of the English language will say : "sure, makes sense".

And does it make sense only when in fact I do have a car and a donkey?  No. The statement also makes sense if I don't have a car or a donkey. It would still make sense to say that *if* I have a car and a donkey, then I would have a car.

And again, we don't say that "*if* I have a car and a donkey, then I have a car." is true because of how the $\to$ is mathematically defined. Rather, it is just the other way around:  the $\to$ is mathematically defined the way that it is because of arguments like the one provided in your textbook: because speakers of the English language regard "*if* I have a car and a donkey, then I have a car" to always be true.

Comment: Thanks @Bram28, I understand that completely. But the author invokes $(C\land D)\Rightarrow C$ even for cases where $C$ and $D$ are not True. In that case, I don't understand how he can make the claim... I understand that it is technically true according to the truth table, but he is trying to motivate the definition of the truth table. And I don't see any other justification for him writing that other than the truth table...

Comment: @MaanDoabeDa The justification is that $C$ is implied by the very $C \land D$ statement. That is, $C \land D$ claims that both $C$ and $D$ are true, so if $C \land D$ is true, then $C$ is true as well. And that  is not because of the truth-table of the conditional, but because of the conjunction. So this is really not circular.

Comment: "That is, C∧D claims that both C and D are true" I don't think this is correct at least in the context of this question.

In parts (ii) and (iii) of the question, $C\land D$ evaluates to false. When it evaluates to true, I think we are both in agreement about why the implication is sensible.

Comment: @MaanDoabeDa $C \land D$ is the *claim* that $C$ and $D$ are both true.  That does not mean that it is actually true. President Trump *claims* lots of things ... but that does not make any of them true either.  But, if the claim $C \land D$ is true, then the claim $C$ will be true as well. And *that* is the claim $(C \land D) \to C$.

Comment: I think I can rephrase my confusion then. Why is the claim $(C\land D)\Rightarrow C$ evaluated as True irrespective of the particular values of $C$ and $D$?

Comment: @MaanDoabeDa The logical connectives that we matjematically define are meant to capture certain truth-functional relationships. The $\land$, for example, is mean to try and capture what we mean by the English 'and'. When we say '$C$ and $D$', we are claiming that both $C$ and $D$ are true. You see this reflected in the truth-table.  So it is not that $C$ and $D$' is true because the truth-table says so, but rathjer that we define the truth-table in a way so as to reflect what we mean by 'and'. (continued)

Comment: Likewise, we try to capture the truth-functional relationship expressed by any English 'if ... then ...' statement by mathematically defining a $\to$ truth-functional operator. Now, our conception of the 'if ... then ...' is such that when we say 'If both $C$ and $D$ are true, then in particular $C$ is true by itself', we expect to have just stated a true 'if ... then ...' claim.  And, we feel that this should be true no matter the truths of $C$ and $D$. If I say 'If I have a car and a donkey, then I have a car', then any 'normal' speaker of the English language wil say : " sure, makes sense"

Comment: And does it make sense only when in fact I do have a car and a donkey?  No. The statement also makes sense if I don;t have a car or a donkey. It would still make sense to say that *if* I have a car and a donkey, then I would have a car. So again, we don;t say that "*if* I have a car and a donkey, then I have a car." is true because of how the $\to$ is mathematically defined, but rather that the $to$ is mathematically defined because spekaers of the language language regard "*if* I have a car and a donkey, then I have a car." to always be true.

Comment: I think the appeal to English is helping. I'm going to think about this for awhile when I get a second. It may be helpful to place parts of your last two comments into your formal answer.

Comment: @MaanDoabeDa Yeah, I already copied those comments into my Answer

Answer (score 4):

We do not take implication as some form of causality, but as a form of logical consequence, i.e., that the truth of a first thing forces us to accept that a second thing is true. The essence of "and" is: that one thing *and* another are true necessitates that each of these two things is true. So with $C\land D$ representing the statement that $C$ *and* $D$ are true forces us to accept that $C$ is true (it also forces us to accept that $D$ is true). If you do not agree, you may have an unusual notion of "and" (or of implication). And this fact, i.e.,  that the truth of $C\land D$ forces us to accept that $C$ is true. The accepting-force behind this argument is always correct, no matter whether $C\land D$ itself is *actually* true. This now precisely what $(C\land D)\Rightarrow C$ symbolizes.

Comment: Hmm... I'm going to add the rest of the question, because he doesn't state that $C$ and $D$ are both true always. Please see if the added parts of the question change anything to your understanding of my question.

Comment: To be clear, I understand what you are saying about the case where $C\land D$ evaluates to true.

Comment: "The accepting-force behind this argument is always correct, no matter whether C∧D itself is actually true." This statement of yours is probably at the center of my confusion. Could you possibly expand on it?  In particular I'm not sure what is meant by accepting-force

Answer (score 2):

A more standard truth table:

[image]

I don't see what $C\land D \implies C$ has to do with it, but the truth table for IMPLIES can be justified as follows using a form of natural deduction:

[image]

---

[image]

[image]

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: This may very well be useful for others who stumble on this question, but it will take me a few more months to be able to process what you have written here.

Comment: @MaanDoabeDa It shouldn't take more than an hour or two. Try downloading DC Proof 2.0 (freeware) at my homepage ( http://www.dcproof.com ) and working through the tutorial (Examples 1-3). Should be a snap for anyone reading Mendelson. Write to me if you have any problems.

Comment: Hey, cool bit of software! I'll try and take a look. I only said it would take me a few more months because I'm mostly studying this stuff alongside my physics PhD, so I don't get to spend as much time as I'd like learning math :(

Answer (score 1):

About the implication connector,

to avoid the cases where the hypothesis is false, and we say that the implication is true,

I purpose a new truth table for the implication .

$(P \implies Q) \;\; P \;\; Q$

$ T   \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; \;\;\;   T.       \;\;\;\;    T$

$  T  \;\;\;\; \;\;\;\;\; \;\;\;\; F.       \;\;\;\;   ?$

$ F.     \; \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;  \;\;\; T.       \;\;\;\;    ?$

$  F.    \;\;\;\;\;\;\;  \;\;\;\; F.          \;\;\;\; ?$

Comment: Salam Abdallah, I edited the question to include the entire portion from the book. The author doesn't only deal with the case where the conjunction evaluates to true, where, I would agree that the implication seems obvious. Does that change your understanding of my question?

Comment: I have tried to look something up about the simplification argument. For example I found: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/discrete_mathematics/rules_of_inference.htm

It seems to me that in the simplification argument, C and D would have to be assumed to be true, in which case the result is obvious. But as the author continues on, he demonstrates that he is not only considering this case.

Comment: Thank you @hamam, I don't quite understand the table, but I also don't see how it would help to change the truth table itself, seeing as my confusion is with the table...